# Converting Processing (cursor) file into a website

Tags: javascript, java, html, cursor, processing

I made a cursor in Processing and I would like to use this on my website.

How can I convert it into a `.java` file to add it to my HTML file?

Comment: You can't use Java on websites, only JavaScript, a completely separate language. What exactly is a cursor in this context? You can set a vector image as cursor using basic CSS: `html { min-height: 100%; cursor: url(url_to_image), auto }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Processing on a webpage, you either have to use Processing.js or P5.js.

But like Chris G said, it's not really clear what exactly you mean by "cursor" here. When most people say that, they mean an image file, in which case you can just use CSS to customize the cursor.

But if you mean you used Processing to create effects using the mouse pointer, then you're going to have to use Processing.js or P5.js, not Java mode. This also means that you won't be able to use any Java libraries in your sketch.

If you have any other questions, please include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates exactly what you're trying to do.